# Asp.net C# DDD - Implementando Web Api

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, ddd, simple-injector

Estou desenvolvendo um Sistema, de estrutura DDD com Simple Injector.

Ao desenvolver a WEB API, os dados retornados do BD estão null.

Em outros testes realizados na view MVC, os mesmos dados são retornados normalmente. O problema está na implantação da injeção de dependência, só que não consigo identificar onde.

**Implementação do Simple Injector**

```
    [assembly: WebActivator.PostApplicationStartMethod(typeof(App_Start.SimpleInjectorWebApiInitializer), "Initialize")]

namespace Api.App_Start
{
    using System.Web.Http;
    using SimpleInjector;
    using SimpleInjector.Integration.WebApi;
    using SimpleInjector.Lifestyles;          

    public static class SimpleInjectorWebApiInitializer
    {
        /// <summary>Initialize the container and register it as Web API Dependency Resolver.</summary>
        public static void Initialize()
        {
            var container = new Container();
            container.Options.DefaultScopedLifestyle = new AsyncScopedLifestyle();

            InitializeContainer(container);
            container.RegisterWebApiControllers(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
            container.Verify();

            GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new SimpleInjectorWebApiDependencyResolver(container);
        }

        private static void InitializeContainer(Container container)
        {
            IoC.Bindings.Start(container);
        }
    }
}
```

**IoC**

```
namespace IoC
{
    public class Bindings
    {
        public static void Start(Container container)
        {
            //Infrastrutura
            container.Register<IRepositoryManager, RepositoryManager>();
            container.Register<IWorkUnit, WorkUnit>();
            //container.Register(typeof(IBaseRepositories<>), typeof(BaseRepositories<>), Lifestyle.Scoped);
            container.Register(typeof(IUsuarioRepositories), typeof(UsuarioRepositories), Lifestyle.Scoped);
            container.Register(typeof(ISistemaRepositories), typeof(SistemaRepositories), Lifestyle.Scoped);

            //Dominio
            container.Register(typeof(IUsuarioDomain), typeof(UsuarioDomain), Lifestyle.Scoped);
            container.Register(typeof(ISistemaDomain), typeof(SistemaDomain), Lifestyle.Scoped);

            //Service Locator
            ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => new SimpleInjectorServiceLocatorAdapter(container));
        }
    }
}
```